# Links are firing after jQuery sortables is stopped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

My sortable list is a bunch of links.  The links should not fire when the user is sorting the list or after they let go of the mouse to stop sorting.  With the following code, the links are being executed when the user lets go of the mouse.  Is there a way to prevent this?

```
$("#applications").sortable({
    start: function () {
        $(".app_link").unbind("click")
    },
    stop: function () {
        $(".app_link").bind("click", function () {...stuff to do...})
    }
});
```

Comment: What browser are you using? I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/r7jA5/1/) and it seems fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the elements are being move they have the .ui-sortable-helper class added to them.  It can be used to exempt them from the binding.

```
$("#applications").sortable();
$(".app_link:not(.ui-sortable-helper)").live("click", function () {...stuff to do...});
```